# Uart not reading whole message in C++

Tags: c++, uart, termios

I'm using termios to read lines out of a uart device, though its behaving erratically. I'm using blocking canonical mode and I'm finding that most of the time my I'm only receiving the back end of my messages. The flags I have enabled are: ICRNL, ICANON, ISIG, CLOCAL, O_RDWR, O_NOCTTY, and CREAD. My baud rate is 38400.

The messages out of the device are terminated with a carriage return, and I've used a logic analyzer to see that the signals coming in and out of the device are what I expect.

```
//The code for all of our flags
uart.inputModes.IgnoreCharactersWithParityError = false;
uart.localModes.CanonicalInput = true;
uart.localModes.EnableSignals = true;
uart.controlModes.ParityEnabled = false;
uart.controlModes.IgnoreModemStatusLines = true;
uart.controlModes.EnableReceiver = true;
uart.inputModes.MapCR_To_NL = true;

uart.openDeviceUart();

int readArraySize = 50;
unsigned char readData[readArraySize];
memset(readData, 0, readArraySize);
uart.SendBytes("$C01,03,41\r");

int myBytes = uart.ReadBytes(readData, readArraySize);
std::cout << "Bytes Received: " << myBytes << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < readArraySize; i++) {
    std::cout << (char) readData[i];
}



uart.CLOSE();
```

Comment: Do you have code?

Comment: Is your code C or C++?

Comment: Edited to include some of my code.

Comment: Should only output myBytes of chars. Are you looping? You really need to read all the chars somehow. You may find stuff is buffered. Usually there is a method to find out how many chars are available to read.

Comment: the uart.Readbytes function stores the data it reads in the readData array, and the number of bytes it read in the variable myBytes.

Comment: I guess uart.Readbytes blocks and waits and myBtyes is typically readArraySize. You should, however, be printing myBytes times in the loop. Normally you ask if bytes are available, or how many bytes are available, and just read those. Give up is nothing becomes available after some time. Also check that there are no bytes available before you start. May be read those and throw away or flush them.

Comment: *"The flags I have enabled are..."* -- That's not an adequate substitution for posting your actual termios code, which is likely to be part of (if not) the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the cause of my issue. My termios code was correct, and my signals looked about what we expected, but the command we were using for the device started a stream, and we were opening that each time we wanted to do a read. Thanks you all for the help.